# Can I have two apps in one webpage in Dart + polymer?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a dart + polymer app, which I have uploaded to my home page. The entry point is not index.html. It works fine.

I have now developed a home page, index.html, again in polymer and dart. Essentially, it's another app of course. It's n the same top level folder as my app.  I've been playing around uploading (which takes **ages!**) the **packages** subfolders, but can't get index.html to display at all - yet.

So my question is, will the **packages** subfolders conflict with each other, and I shouldn't do it?

Thanks

cheers
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are both polymer apps on the exact same version and all their packages are the exact same version then you might be ok, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Instead, can you make a single package which has two entry points (one for each of your apps)? If you want to keep your code separate for each of them you can do that still by moving everything into the lib folder and using a git or path dependency on each package (you probably don't want to publish your apps to pub).

Comment: Good idea!  Thanks. I'll try that and will report report back here. Cheers.